# Как убрать кнопку в navbar?

Tags: php, yii2

```
<div class="row" id="header_menu">
        <nav>
            <?php
            NavBar::begin([
                'brandLabel' => false,
                'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
                'options' => ['class' => 'topmenu']
            ]);
            echo Nav::widget([
                'options' => ['class' => 'topmenu'],
                'items' => [
                    ['label' => 'Главная', 'url' => ['web/theme/index']]
                ]
            ]);
            NavBar::end()
            ?>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

Что это и как это убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это кнопка вызова меню  для   устройство с маленьким экраном

Comment: Как ее убрать? Я когда нажимаю на нее, она неадекватно себя ведет, открывается и сразу закрывается.

Comment: Можете скрыть средствами CSS, можете изменить сам widget, удалите от туда ToggleButton

Comment: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950716/override-bootstrap-css-in-yii2)

Comment: Есть ли большая разница писать навбар на html или делать его через средства yii ?

Comment: Если есть возможность сделать вывод ссылки автоматически, то можете и в html сделать